# Restore DB from different Version SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, database-backups

Could you help me?

I want to copying full database from SQL Server 2014 to SQL Server 
2008.
I try to use SQL server Export Wizard, but it took too long times for copying and dragging my network, because the DB size larger than 100GB.

So I try to create a test, make a new database in SQL Server 2014 and backup into `.BAK`, then I copy the `.BAK` file to drive where SQL Server 2008 are.
I try to restore the `.BAK` file in SQL Server 2008.

I have choose the path where .BAK file is, but SQL seems like can't read the .BAK file.

[This is notification while I try to restore the database.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VZg5Y.jpg)

Comment: You can **never** go back in SQL Server -  a backup from a more recent version (2014) in **incompatible** and not usable by any earlier version of SQL Server. You will need to create SQL scripts to create the database in SQL Server 2008 and possibly to fill in base data

Comment: @marc-syes, I have search for the answer. now I try to use linked server and transfer with script, but it take too long. there is a way to transfer 100GB DB with more efficient and save more time?

Answer (score 0):

You can not restore backup sql server 2014 to sql server 2012,2008,2005
you can use generate sql script with data.

Comment: you have same answer with @marc_eyes. I have search for the answer. now I try to use linked server and transfer with script, but it take too long. there is a way to transfer 100GB DB with more efficient and save more time?

Comment: I think you can use SSIS

Comment: Generating script is a good option, but it doesn't work good with larger databases.

Comment: I think first of all generate scripts of all object with out data and then you can table to table transfer data by Import/Export tools.